# Best practices for importing deeply nested Javascript components

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, reactjs, sprockets

I am working on a Ruby/React project. We are using React components and CoffeeScript and final JS is assembled by Sprockets:

```
#= require org/components/whatever

{ Whatever } = Org.Components
```

It is okay when there is not too much nesting and then you are wrtiting something like this:

```
#= require org/components/whatever
#= require org/components/something/else/whatever

{ Whatever1 } = Org.Components
{ Whatever2 } = Org.Components.Something.Else
```

Today I was trying to find where `Org.Components.Image.Upload` is used. But sometimes it is imported as `{ Upload }` or used as `Image.Upload` and it doesn't make things easier.

Now I am thinking maybe don't go further than `Org.Components` for imports. So if you need `Image.Upload` — get `{ Image } = Org.Components`, and use `Image.Upload`. If it gets too long - assign to a variable.

```
#= require org/components/image

{Image} = Org.Components
Upload = Image.Super.Complex.Upload

# Or use it like this for explicitness
render: ->
  Image.Super.Complex.Upload
```

What is the best practice here? I want code to be searchable.

Comment: Local references to objects can help decrease lookup times, which is what it seems that you're doing, but if it's organized, the _Dependency Declaration Pattern_ can be incredibly useful and convenient.

Comment: I usually use that method when working with deeply nested objects.

Comment: I don't think there is a best practise. But you certainly shouldn't be mixing them, use *either* destructuring *or* variable assignment.

Comment: Another alternative: `{Components: {Image}} = Org;`

Comment: The problem is - this is not searchable. I want to be able to tell where the component is used for easier refactoring.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a CommonJS environment (Node), and probably using a module bundler like [Webpack](https://webpack.github.io) or [Browserify](http://browserify.org) you can take advantage of the direct module imports. For example:

Instead of doing this `Org.Components.Image`, you can do that:

```
import Upload from 'org/components/Image/Super/Complex/Upload'
// or var Image = require('org/components/Image/Super/Complex/Upload');
```

In your original strategy you load the entire library (org) to further filter it down to `Upload`.

In the proposed solution above, you only load the Image module and nothing else. This will probably save you a lot of bits in your final footprint, specially if `org` contains a big pile of components used inside your company.

Comment: The question is what if I am reusing Image.Upload separately

Comment: Sorry if I got your question wrong. But the point I'm trying to make is to always refer only to the module you are looking for in a given dependecy. In your scenario, I would say the best practice is to always set the entire path for the Upload component. Hopefully I'm making some sense here.

Answer (score 0):

To stop fighting against the sprockets I have defined a Root component that tells Sprockets where to look for the subcomponents:

```
# components/branding.coffee

 #= require_tree ./branding

Org.Components.Branding = {}
```

So now if I need anything from the branding subtree I simply do the following:

```
#= require org/components/branding

{div} = React.DOM

{Branding} = Org.Components

Org.defineComponent "Settings.Branding",
  render: ->
    div {},
      Branding.Edit.ContactUs {}
      Branding.Config {},
        Branding.Edit
```

This way I don't need to worry about dependencies and found it to be much more pleasant to work with.

I would suggest that this approach helps refactoring as you don't have to change multiple requires everywhere.

`Branding.Config` is a data-wrapped that loads and syncs settings. In the example above it is used to load settings for the `Brading.Edit` page. And here it is loading branding for in 'Layouts.Default'.

And again I only require `branding`

```
# apps/src/org/components/layouts/default.coffee

#= require org/components/branding

{Branding, TenantStateBar, UnsupportedBrowserBar} = Org.Components

Org.defineComponent 'Layouts.Default',
  render: ->
    div {},
      Branding.Config {},
        Branding.Style
```